# How to clone field in Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm configuring Kafka Connect to copy data from Kafka to Database

I need to put value from some field to two column in Database .

My Kafka Message has two fields `name`, `age`. Target table has 3 columns `name`, `displayName` and `age`. I would like to clone value of `name` from Kafka message to put it in both columns `name` and `displayName`.

Is there any Transform, that can by applied to do that?

Comment: You can try to use a transformation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html#insertfield

Comment: I read about default transforms, but how I understand InsertField allows you to add field with static value or with metadata information from message (ex. topic name partitions, etc), or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Driss Nejjar says, this would typically be the kind of thing that a Single Message Transform would be perfect for. However, there is no Transform that ships with Apache Kafka that I can see that would do this. You could [write your own](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html), or you could also use KSQL:

```
CREATE STREAM new AS SELECT name, name as displayName, age FROM source;
```

This would take your `source` topic (populated by Connect), and add the additional field `displayName`, and write to a new Kafka topic called `new`.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, the company behind the KSQL project.*